# Can you do implode .= in php?

Tags: php, implode

Not sure if I ask this correctly, correct me if I am wrong.
I know you need an array to do implode, Instead adding a space after `</a>`, I want to do an implode in `.=`

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$lastPage; $i++) {  
    $pageLink .= "<a href='ajax.php?action=merchantlist&merchant_id=" . $merchant_id . "p=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";  
};  
$pageLinks = implode(' ', $pageLink);
```

Comment: No. `.=` is making a string, not an array. Just add a space at the end of that line. You could use `rtrim` outside the loop if you want to remove the last space. Also `p` is not going to be a parameter in the link you are building, you need an `&` unless `$merchant_id` has that?

Comment: What are you trying do do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.= Means to append to the previously defined variable (string mostlikely). So in your case you are alrady craeting a string out of your loop to the exception that your variable has not been initialized.

So you could do something like this and remove the implode:

```
$pageLink="";
for ($i=1; $i<=$lastPage; $i++) {  
    $pageLink .= "<a href='ajax.php?action=merchantlist&merchant_id=" . $merchant_id . "p=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";  
};  
echo $pageLink;
```

or create an array (like your original question is asking for) but i think it is an unessecary step. (initalize an array, to call an function to make the string) as when you could just use 1 varaible and avoid the function threshold by appending to it (like in my 1st snippet).

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$lastPage; $i++) {  
    $pageLink[] = "<a href='ajax.php?action=merchantlist&merchant_id=" . $merchant_id . "p=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";  
};  
$pageLinks = implode(' ', $pageLink);

    echo $pageLinks;
```

also i think you are missing an & in your string before the "p="

```
$pageLink .= "<a href='ajax.php?action=merchantlist&merchant_id=" . $merchant_id . "p=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
```

should be with an & before the p= like so

```
$pageLink .= "<a href='ajax.php?action=merchantlist&merchant_id=" . $merchant_id . "&p=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
```

Another thing, i would url_encode anything in your href that could be a string so an appostrophe won'T break your html attribute.